# On nearly the same day last

Tags: prepositions

***On nearly the same day last*** week that Czech PM Bohuslav Sobotka sharply criticized the policy of the US, UK and France in Syria, American journalist Michael Bohm appeared on Russian state TV and defended his own government's actions there.

Source: http://www.fsfinalword.com/?page=archive&show=1&day=2016-12-19

Would it be possible to replace the passage in bold with "At almost the same day…"?

Comment: No. "**at** the same **day**" is ungrammatical. **day** and **time** are not interchangeable in this regard.  *day* is a span. *time* is a point.  **at** with points in time, **on** with days and spans of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have reordered it to, "Last week, practically on the same day that ..."

"Almost" works as well, but I would still use "on" not "at".

> Last week, almost on the same day that ...

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions

> - On nearly the same day
> - At almost the same day

have the same meaning. *Last* modifies *week* and you need to keep it.